# Listener For Enter Click within ListView Footer

Tags: android

I want to have an edit text as a footer in my listView so I am able to add a comment. I can add the edittext to the listview no problem but I receive no events to the listener I set. Any ideas why?

```
    editText = new EditText(getActivity());
    editText.setHint("add comment");
    editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    getListView().addFooterView(editText);
    editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d(DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName(), "pressed");
            return false;
        }
    });
    setListAdapter(commentAdapter);
```

Comment: The action comes when you press newline ( enter ) button.

Comment: I receive nothing when I click the enter button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line too:

```
editText.setSingleLine(true);
```

Moreover i recommend instead of using this editText as FooterView, You aling that editText to the parentBottom and have the ListView above it. That way user don't need to go to the end of the list and then realize he/she can comment too.